# SharePoint 2010 How to automatically add numbers from different lists.

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have 2 lists. List A and List B.
List A is for users to add their price.
List B is for totalprice, and when a user enters a new item in List A, it should automatically add onto List B
For example: input 1: User adds $400 from list A.
List B should automatically update totalprice to $400. 
Then another user adds $600 from List A.
List B should add that $600 onto the already existing $400. so it should automatically update to $1000 and so on....basically a budget tracker

I've tried playing around with SPD to try and make this work but am struggling to do so. Please if anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe view column aggregation will do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

What about to implement EventReceiver on list A and do in a code update of list B?!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010(v=office.14).aspx